# Pyhton OpenCV "callback" Function and the "nothing" in Trackbar use for Image Processing

Tags: python, opencv, callback

I still don't get it, what is the function of 'callback' for trackbar that uses in image processing with OpenCV, python

```
# A required callback method that goes into the trackbar function.
def nothing(x):
    pass

# Create a window named trackbars.
cv2.namedWindow("Trackbars")

# Now create 6 trackbars that will control the lower and upper range of 
# H,S and V channels. The Arguments are like this: Name of trackbar, 
# window name, range,callback function. For Hue the range is 0-179 and
# for S,V its 0-255.
cv2.createTrackbar("L - H", "Trackbars", 0, 179, nothing) 
cv2.createTrackbar("L - S", "Trackbars", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("L - V", "Trackbars", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("U - H", "Trackbars", 179, 179, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("U - S", "Trackbars", 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("U - V", "Trackbars", 255, 255, nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the callback function you can define what has to happen if the slider changes (see [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d6a/tutorial_trackbar.html)).

Here is a very simple example on how to use the callback with one slider:

```
import cv2


img_original = cv2.imread("img.png")
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

win_name = "Image"
cv2.namedWindow(win_name)


def on_change_lightness(trackbar_value):
    img_hsv[:, :, 2] = trackbar_value
    out = cv2.cvtColor(img_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    cv2.imshow(win_name, out)


cv2.createTrackbar('Lightness', win_name, 50, 255, on_change_lightness)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In your case you can write a separate callback function for each slider that changes the respective value and redraws the the image.

Comment: I think you'd get your point across better if you renamed that variable from `x` to `trackbar_value` or something like that.